# Is there a way to find the id of an ajax xmlhttprequest?

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest

One of my pages has about 5 jQuery AJAX calls that fire off as soon as the page loads. I want to track each AJAX call individually and get it an id. How do I do this?

Comment: I would start with the Firebug extension for the Firefox browser. The Chrome browser also has the xmlhttp request id in it's developer tools.

Comment: thank you very  much,but where come from the xmlhttp request id that the Chrome browser has

Answer (score 2):

Download the Firefox browser and install the Firebug extension. That will let you track all the XMLHTTP request information for each request (as well as help you with plenty of other debugging issues).

Here's a basic overview: http://getfirebug.com/network